# How can I enforce a specific version of the .net framework

Tags: .net, build-automation

We were under the impression that setting the target framework on the properties of a solution would limit that app to using only that framework or below's functionality. We just found out though, that someone can add a reference and start using code from a higher versioned framework and the compiler won't complain one bit. Since we would like to prevent this in the future does anyone have any ideas on how I could detect something referencing a higher version or not? I need to fail the build if someone adds code above our target.

Comment: imho that flag only disallows language (clr) features of higher frameworks, not libraries..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're targeting .NET 2.0 and above... your build could fail if you detect references to System.Core or other 3.x assemblies (e.g. WPF) in References of your projects.

**UPDATE**

You could start with checking inside each `.PROJ` file for:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Then, inside the `<ItemGroup>` tag:

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

This could be a custom NAnt task or write your own parser to look for these nodes and fail the build.

Comment: And how would you detect these? I have looked at the manifests, the proj files, and alike. And, without a global list of each dll and which version it is in I cannot figure out how to best determine. Good news is I have tested VS 2010 and it does enforce this, so the best option just may be to wait for 2010 and upgrade immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to prevent this if it works?  As long as you don't use any of the new features, I believe it is possible to have "forward" compatible DLLs.

Comment: We wish to make sure a developer doesn't accidently/unknowingly add use any of the new features.

Comment: I would expect the compiler to catch these problems for you.  If not the compiler, then any unit tests would catch it for sure.